# Hypothesis testing on a model's inference

Tags: hypothesis-testing, standard-error, z-test

I have the following situation, which I've mapped to an example below.
At the conclusion of an A/B test done on a website I've a metric I care about. Let's assume its the number of users clicking on a signup button with the control set of users seeing a blue colored button while the treatment sees a red button. We observe a statistically significant lift in proportion of users clicking on the signup button in treatment vs control. So far so good. Separately a machine learned model **M** which has been trained on a set of user features **F**, forecasts whether the customer will stay in the service and not cancel the service in future weeks conditional on them signing up for the service. The model has been trained independently of the bucket test of course. The forecasts the model makes is for (say) 1 week after a customer signs up. My question is

- Is there a way to do a statistical hypothesis test on model's forecast for the 1 week window? My attempt is the following. For each of the weeks have the model **M** emit the average probability of customers in the control group staying in the service $p_1$ its pooled uncertainty of its forecasts $\sigma_1^2$ and compare that to the treatment group's metrics $p_2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ *alongwith* the standard error of the proportions, eventually yielding

$ z = \frac{p_2 - p_1}{\sqrt{\frac{p_1(1-p_1)}{n} + \sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2} }$

Am I thinking about this right? Or is the act of using model forecasts in hypothesis testing fundamentally flawed? Any guidance / pointers appreciated.

Comment: What is the null hypothesis you want to test? Whether $p_1$ and $p_2$ are equal?

Comment: Yes. Alternative is $p_1  \lt p_2$

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are trying to achieve. Maybe shorten and clarify your question. I suppose you want to test whether the "staying probability" differs between treatment an control group. If so, you could in principle use your model outputs as estimates of that probability. But why not wait until the actual behavior was observed and then test?

Comment: Also, is your detailed explanation of the A-B test at the beginning necessary for the question? Maybe shorten there.

Comment: Basically if we had models forecasting proportions for two groups, is it fair to do a ztest of proportions on the forecast as we would assuming we had direct measures of the proportions? Or do we do a ztest of proportions by somehow factoring in the variance of the forecast too as I've called out in the question. I think the details of an example helps instantiate my question better.

Comment: You can do a statistical test if you know (at least approximately) the distribution of your test statistic under the null hypothesis. It is usually called z-test if that test statistic is approximately normal. If you can construct such a test statistic with your model output, you are good to go. What distribution the $z$ you propose has under your null, I cannot tell from the question.